# Close all windows only closes one Excel instance

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-365

On windows 10, if I have a number of instances of an application open, I can simply right click the icon on the taskbar and select `Close all windows`

If I try this with Excel, only one workbook closes so I have to perform the operation multiple times.

I can kill them all with Powershell but that is a bit of a large hammer to crack this nut and causes Document Recovery to be started when I next open the workbooks.

I could understand this if I was making changes and hadn't saved them but these are all workbooks I'm simply reading - not updating.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does not Document Recovery tell you that changes had been made.  e.g. =NOW() function?  This will make Excel think changes had been made. That is why Close All does not work as you wish

Comment: In my Windows 10 enivronment, clicking the "Close all windows" entry (inside the Excel icon) does exactly what you are asking for. Hm.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann As a test, I just created 3 clean workbooks and it closed 2 but left one open - go figure! :(